# Merge labels from lines with duplicate fields

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, awk, duplicate

I have a rather large text file(thousands of lines) in following format:

```
123.123 5  
123.123 91  
156.456 45  
233.185 85  
233.185 4  
257.448 1  
455.456 60  
455.456 2
```

The first column are sorted coordinates (x.y) and the second one is the label (0 to 1000). As it can be seen the coordinate 123.123 has label 5 and label 91 or coordinates 156.456 has only label 45

I want another file as output with all the coordinates (not duplicate) and the different labels (this label will appear several times duplicate), the output for this example must be:

```
123.123  5   91  
156.456  45   
233.185  85  4  
257.448  1  
455.456  60  2
```

My idea was to remove duplicate strings (coordinates, so only first column), leaving alone labels and then reorganize the lines or another way but I am stuck with which commands to use.
Another option is with databases.

Answer (score 1):

looks like an awk's job

```
 awk '{ c[$1]=c[$1] "\t" $2 ; } END { for ( c2 in c ) printf c2 c[c2] "\n" ; } '
```

where

- `c[$1]=c[$1] "\t" $`2 will store label,
- `END` clause is run at end of file.
- `for ( c2 in c ) printf c2 c[c2] "\n" ;` will lopp through coordinates, printing label.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -p0e 'while(s/^(\S+)( .*)(\n\1)/\1\2/m){}'
```

The basic idea is:

- `-p0` load the file in memory and print it in the end;
- `-e` execute the next argument on the loaded file
- while possible, substitute `<word> <line>\n<word>` by `<word> <line>`

Comment: maybe edit your post to add a few line to explain, just in case someone came with a similar problem but with 4 columns or some variation ?

Comment: @Archemar, thank you for the wise sugestion.